# System.out.println() stops working after JNA/DLL call?

Tags: java, dll, jna, system.out

I have multiple System.out.println() calls in my program. My issue is that, after making a call to a DLL through a JNA Library (which does work without returning an error code or throwing an exception), subsequent calls to println() execute without printing anything! I know that the statements are executing because I'm stepping through them in NetBeans!

Unfortunately, I don't have a clue about the C code behind the DLL, and I guess you won't be able to duplicate this unless you register with qimaging.com and download the QCam SDK. I'm just wondering if anyone has experienced anything similar to this System.out.println() behavior, i.e. that it works until a certain point, then stops printing even though it executes.

This is my main test class:

```
package hwi.scope;

import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import hwi.scope.qcam.QCamDriverX64;
import java.io.File;

/**
* QCamTest class tests some functions of the QCam driver library.
* @author rnagel
*/
public class QCamTest
{
    private static QCamDriverX64 driver;

    // Main test method:
    public static void main() throws Exception
    {
        // Set path to easily find DLL in the /dll folder:
        File f = new File("dll");        
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", f.getCanonicalPath());        

        // Use JNA to load the driver library:
        driver = QCamDriverX64.INSTANCE;

        // Load camera driver from the library:
        loadQCamDriver();

        // Print out the driver version:
        printQCamVersion();
    }

    // Load camera driver method:
    public static void loadQCamDriver()
    {
        System.out.println("Loading QCam driver..."); // Executes and prints to console
        int error = driver.QCam_LoadDriver();        
        System.out.println("Done loading driver."); // Executes, but doesn't print to console
    }

    // Print camera driver version:
    public static void printQCamVersion()
    {
        // Obtain driver version as a combination of 'major' and 'minor' increments:
        IntByReference major = new IntByReference(), minor = new IntByReference();
        int error = driver.QCam_Version(major, minor);

        // At this point, I've verified that I have a obtained a valid version.
        System.out.println("QCam v." + major.getValue() + "." + minor.getValue()); // Executes, but doesn't print to console   
    }
}
```

And this is the QCamDriverX64 class that I've made to wrap the DLL:

```
package hwi.scope.qcam;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

/**
 * QCamDriverX64 wraps the 64-bit version of the QCam driver DLL.
 * @author rnagel
 */
public interface QCamDriverX64 extends Library {

    // Make the library name publicly accessible:
    public static final String DLL_NAME = "QCamDriverx64";

    // Load an instance of the library using JNA:
    public static final QCamDriverX64 INSTANCE = (QCamDriverX64) Native.loadLibrary(DLL_NAME, QCamDriverX64.class);

    // Load the QCam driver:
    int QCam_LoadDriver();

    // Obtain QCam driver version # (in major and minor increments)
    int QCam_Version (IntByReference major, IntByReference minor);
}
```

I'm using NetBeans 8.2 and JDK 1.8.0_121.

Thanks for taking a look! I'd appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily reproduce that by calling

```
System.out.close();
System.err.close();
```

I'm assuming that the native code in the DLL is doing something in that respect. It might be friendly by actually doing above call. In that case you could save `System.out` and `System.err` into variables, set some dummy streams with `System.setOut()` and `System.setErr()` and put everything back as it was before after the DLL-call. If the native code closes the underlying file handles, that won't help and the only option is to file a bug report at the provider of the DLL.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out and try some things. I should have mentioned that System.err seems unaffected; it's only System.out that stops printing.

Comment: Ok, I tried swapping a dummy stream in place of the original; but it still affected the original System.out stream. This time I also used OutputStream.checkError(), and I saw that it was false before and after the DLL call, but true after the next failed attempt to println().

Comment: On Linux, try using strace to see what the DLL is doing. On Windows, see API Monitor and restrict the calls to the QCam DLL. See if it's closing the stream.

Comment: @cubrr What is "API Monitor"? Is it a program I can download from somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: @RaymondNagel Yes, it's a downloadable download. Although, doesn't the SDK come with documentation? Possibly an `QCam API.pdf` according to my google-fu? What does it say about the function you're calling?

Comment: @cubrr The PDF says: "The first call you must make is QCam_LoadDriver(). This initializes QCam and prepares it for communication with the camera." It doesn't say anything about a stream. Also, the recommended language to be used is either C or C++; it says Java can also be used, but would require writing a small wrapper layer to call into the QCam API. Actually I have written such a layer in VB.Net years ago for this API; but there was no such issue with an output stream being affected.
I've just downloaded the API Monitor, so I'll check it out. Thanks.